# In Catharism, did they use as a guide any books of the Bible and if so, which?

Tags: church-history, gnosticism, catharism

Cathars are known for having been a community which did not believe good things about the Old Testament deity and were based in the Languedoc region of today's southern France around the 12th century. Given that most Christian denominations in existence base their beliefs partly in the Old Testament deity, I was wondering, did the Cathars use as a guide any books of the Bible and if so, which? Were those books different than the ones we know? Did they have additional gospels besides the canon used by most Christians today?

Comment: _The writings of the Cathars were mostly destroyed because of the doctrine's threat perceived by the Papacy;[17] thus, the historical record of the Cathars is derived primarily from their opponents._ See [Wikipedia - Catharism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism) Their doctrine is so heretical and offensive that I am unsurprised at the lack of documentation (which I suggest makes the question unanswerable).

Comment: I did not address level of heresy or offensiveness of Catharism in my question. Although doing a brief  qualitative historical analysis, lacking evidence that the Cathar clerics persecuted, tortured or killed people who didn't believe their teachings and considering the widespread practice of other denominations, specially the Roman Catholic Church, of torturing and murdering "heretics" and anyone who dared criticized the prevailing doctrine, I would say that the Cathar doctrine is benign and certainly offensive to murderous and corrupt denominations.

Comment: **(1).** *Cathars [...] did not believe good things about the Old Testament deity* - Neither do I. **(2).** *most Christian denominations in existence base their beliefs partly in the Old Testament deity* - Not quite; Christianity is based on Christ's (re)interpretation of Judaism, its scriptures, and its deity; which themselves were also a (re)interpretation of [Canaanite paganism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Canaanite_religion), its myths, and its deities.

Comment: @Lucian Did you mean an accurate fulfillment and exposition of Judaism, which itself was a rebuke and correction of Canaanite paganism?

Comment: @MikeBorden: Ancient Canaanites sacrificed their firstborn children to their deities; Jews continued doing (almost) the same thing as their pagan ancestors (Joshua 24:2), save for the fact that, instead of sacrificing the child's entire body, they only offered a small [part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcision) of it; still, old habits die hard, and, apart from sporadic mentions of child sacrifice in post-Abrahamic times, the Old Covenant is riddled with atrocities involving women and children; a remnant of previous cruelty and barbarism.

Comment: @Lucian I've never heard circumcision portrayed as a continuation of child sacrifice before!   Is there any evidence that the prepuce was burned in a fire to Yahweh?  I know there are some who view Yahweh not as the one true God but as one of a pagan many who managed to assert dominance.  However, Scripture seems to portray Yahweh as the one who created all things in the spiritual realm, the physical realm, and even the realms themselves.

Comment: @MikeBorden: Not all sacrifices involve fire; e.g., libations. A relevant passage would be Exodus 4:22-26, for instance. There is no biblical mention circumcision before Abraham (Genesis 17), whose sacrifice of Isaac was ultimately rejected (Genesis 22).

Comment: According to [God's Church Through the Ages](https://www.tomorrowsworld.org/booklets/gods-church-through-the-ages/content),
the Cathars "were remnants of earlier Bogomil settlements [that] had accepted a variety of *new and strange doctrines* and were quite divided among themselves".
They went on a wrong track after continuing the line of faith of the Paulicians, Bogomils, and Waldenses, including celebrating Passover and possibly Sabbath worship, and "regarding the Trinity, purgatory and intercession of the saints as unscriptural".
Perhaps strange to the Catholic Church, but hardly new.

Comment: Doesn't the [Texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism#Texts) section of the *Wikipedia* article answer your question?

Comment: @Lucian Didn't Zipporah do for Moses what Moses should have already done?

Comment: @MikeBorden: The main question is why it was done, not when or by whom.

Comment: @Lucian A token of the Abrahamic covenant, no?  Genesis 17 doesn't read like a sacrifice.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yes, it does. Thanks! Add the answer and I accept it as an answer.

Comment: Because there is some confusion in one of the answers, can you just confirm that by "Cathars" you mean the 12th Century movement centred around southern France nd the subject of the Abigenisian crusade?

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, the Cathars of 12th century Languedoc, today southern France.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer to Questions

(based on [*Wikipedia* article section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism#Texts) quoted below and [Cathar Texts and Rituals](http://gnosis.org/library/cathtx.htm))

**Did the Cathars use as a guide any books of the Bible and if so, which?**

They only accepted a few of the Old Testament books (the rest they regarded written by Satan).  They accepted the New Testament but hold a different interpretation of the [Book of Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation), not as prophecy, but as an allegorical chronicle of what had transpired in Satan's rebellion, with numerous elements characteristic of [Gnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnostic) literature.

**Were those books different than the ones we know?**

- **About their use of the New Testament**

  Four website articles in the **Resources** section below said simply that they use the New Testament which they attribute to the benevolent God, without saying whether they use a different version.  Maybe we can safely assume that they use the same books since by that time (12th century) the canon has long been established.  Of course they read it with a different interpretation, since the mainstream Christian interpretation depends on many typological/ prophetic fulfillment of many Old Testament verses and mainstream interpretation also assumes that the same God was worshiped by the people mentioned in the New Testament.
- **About the few books they use from the Old Testament**

  I cannot find a list of books they use from the Old Testament (yet)

**Did they have additional gospels besides the canon used by most Christians today?**

Yes, [*The Gospel of the Secret Supper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_the_Secret_Supper) (also called *John's Interrogation*).

In addition, they also use the *Ascension of Isaiah* (a compilation of texts which include [*The Vision of Isaiah*](http://gnosis.org/library/Cathar-Vision-Isaiah.htm)), [*The Book of Two Principles*](http://gnosis.org/library/cathar-two-principles.htm), and a few others.

### Resources

- [**Texts** section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism#Texts) of the *Wikipedia* article on [*Catharism*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism):

  > The alleged sacred texts of the Cathars, besides the New Testament, included the previously [Bogomil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogomil) text [*The Gospel of the Secret Supper*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gospel_of_the_Secret_Supper) (also called *John's Interrogation*), a modified version of [*Ascension of Isaiah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_of_Isaiah), and the Cathar original work The Book of the Two Principles (possibly penned by Italian Cathar John Lugio of Bergamo). They regarded the Old Testament as written by Satan, except for a few books which they accepted, and considered the [Book of Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation) not a prophecy about the future, but an allegorical chronicle of what had transpired in Satan's rebellion. Their reinterpretation of those texts contained numerous elements characteristic of [Gnostic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnostic) literature.
- 2019 Book edited by Sebastian C. Garreau: [The Cathar Bible: Translated from the Original Languages and Modern Sources](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/1096624680).  The volume contains the Gospel of John, the Interrogation of John (the Book of the Secret Supper) and the Book of the Two Principles.
- *Gnosis.org* has [Cathar Texts and Rituals](http://gnosis.org/library/cathtx.htm)
- Lecture [Cathar Beliefs, Rituals, and Holy Books](https://www.thegreatcoursesdaily.com/cathar-beliefs-rituals-and-holy-books/) by Richard B. Spence, PhD from the Great Courses Lecture Series [The Real History of Secret Societies](https://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/the-real-history-of-secret-societies.html)

  > **Cathar Holy Books**
  >
  > There are mentions of Cathar holy books like the *Book of Two Principles*, *The Secret Supper*, and the *Interrogation of John*, but the Inquisition zealously destroyed them. Denying the heretics their gospels was seen as key to defeating them. Catholic critics frequently accused the Cathars of witchcraft and sexual perversity.
- Various web articles

  - *ChristianHistoryInstitute.org* article [#211: Cathars Recorded as Heretics](https://christianhistoryinstitute.org/study/module/cathars)
  - *Medievalists.net* article [A Five-Minute Guide to the Cathars](https://www.medievalists.net/2020/04/guide-cathars/)
  - *SacredMysteryTours.com* article [Faith of the Cathars](http://www.sacredmysterytours.com/cathar-faith#sthash.WuwY7MVS.dpbs)
  - *GotQuestions.org* article [What is Catharism?](https://www.gotquestions.org/Catharism.html)
  - Christianity.SE question [Question:What was the explanation for why Catharism identified the Old Testament God as Satan?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54536/10672)

Comment: Thanks! I am still intrigued if the New Testament as they knew it was different from the contemporary one. Because there is more than one reference to the Old Testament in today's New Testament and I don't know to what extent Cathars eschewed the Old Testament.

Comment: @freethinker36 I updated the answer.  I cannot find any mention that the NT is different.  I also cannot find yet the books they did approve from the Old Testament.

Answer (score 1):

The name ‘Cathars’ was given to Christians who adhered to and believed Scripture. They were also known as Puritans. The name ‘Novatians’ was also given to them, though Novatian was not their founder. It was the Donatists in North Africa who were influenced by Novatian, particularly on points of discipline and purity of character for those who would take the sacraments.  After he had been excommunicated in AD 251 by a synod at Rome, then martyred, many Christians who sympathized with his strict standards for Christians spread widely. They ceased to recognize the Catholic churches or to acknowledge any value in their ordinances. Thus the Catholic church would call them ‘heretics’.

In Bosnia, in the 1200s, there was an Italian Inquisitor, Reniero Sacconi, who called some of the disparate groups of non-Catholic Christians “the church of the Cathari” or pure-living, the name used from before the time of Emperor Constantine, and he said they extended from the Black Sea to the Atlantic. The persecutions against them caused them to find refuge from Rome with the Muslims Turks. They preferred the mercies of the Turks to the horrors of the Inquisition.

Rome called these various groups many names, including Manichaeans, in an attempt to blacken their name and justify their persecutions. Rome also destroyed as many of their writings as possible, so we have very little about them apart from what Rome said. Mani, a Persian, lived AD 216-76 and taught dualism (a form of Gnosticism) which led to him leaving the Jewish Christians he’d been brought up amongst. Yes, his views were heretical but such views were in great decline by the sixth century in the West. From the seventh to the twelfth centuries the Paulician movement in Armenia spread, though it repudiated Manichaeism. Still, it resembled it in its dualism views, and helped develop the Bogomils in the Balkans. The Bogomils, in turn, stimulated the Cathars or Albingensians, who were dominant in southern France and northern Italy up till the thirteenth century. The crusade against them by Pope Innocent III in 1208 finally suppressed them by the fourteenth century.

Here is a quote from the book below. It deals with this crusade against such groups in France:

> “The people brought for trial then made a confession of faith which
> did not differ much from what a Roman Catholic might have made; but as
> they had a conscientious objection to taking an oath in confirmation
> of what they had said they were condemned. This confession, including
> as it did a declaration of belief in infant baptism, shows that those
> affected by the religious movements of the time differed among
> themselves in their degree of divergence from the teachings of the
> dominant Church. In a time of such spiritual unrest, all kinds of
> strange and fanciful ideas took root, and both truth and error found
> fruitful ground. Some persons who were examined and punished appear to
> have been Mystics, and although many who were accused of being
> Manichaens had no sort of connection with them, yet instances were
> found of those who held Manichean doctrine, and these were readily
> confounded with others innocent of such teaching.
>
> Among the people the brethren were most frequently called “Good men”,
> and there is general testimony to the fact that their manner of life
> was a pattern to all, and especially that their simplicity and piety
> were a contrast to the self-indulgence of the clergy.” *The Pilgrim
> Church* by E.H. Broadbent, pages 15, 62, 85 (Pickering Classic 1985)

Bear in mind that many people accused by Rome were burned alive at the stake. The goods of the executed would be divided between the church and the civil authority.

> “Pope Gregory IX, in 1263, declared, ‘We excommunicate and
> anathematize all heretics, Cathars, Patarenes, Poor Men of Lyons,
> Passagini, Josepini, Arnaldistae, Speronistrae, and others, by
> whatever names they may be known…” (*Ibid.* p 89)

It seems that Rome felt threatened by these different groups of non-conformists and decided to lump them all together (in order to tar them with the same brush) and to persecute them to extinction. However, if anyone today is under the impression that the Cathars did not believe good things about the Old Testament God, only believing certain parts of the Bible and not all of it, the onus is on them to give documented evidence for that charge, and not just any vague claim that they've heard. Bear in mind, also, that the Cathars were also called by other names, so that any historic search for facts will descend into very muddy waters indeed.

EDIT: One group that did, indeed, repudiate some of the things in the Old Testament were Marcionites. Marcion was born in 85 and published his views when aged nearly 60. His group

> “spread so widely as seriously to rival the Catholic system… He
> adopted a form of dualistic theory such as was prevalent t the time;
> asserting that the world was not created by the Highest God, but by a
> lower being, the god of the Jews… but he was not in agreement with the
> Gnostic sects… He applied his theory to the Scriptures and rejected
> all in them that was in manifest opposition to it… Thus, although he
> had formerly accepted, he later rejected the whole of the Old
> Testament… To [his] abridged New Testament Marcion added his own book,
> ‘Antitheses’, which took the place of the Book of Acts.” (*Ibid.*, pp
> 13-14)

Then the development of resistance groups within decadent churches is related. They hoped to reform the whole but some were cast out and met separately:

> “These would often reinforce those others which, from the beginning,
> had maintained primitive practice. There is frequent reference in
> later centuries to those churches that had adhered to Apostolic
> doctrine, and which h claimed unbroken succession of testimony from
> the time of the Apostles. They often received, both before and after
> the time of Constantine, the name of Cathars, or Puritans, though it
> does not appear that they took this name themselves. The name
> Novatians was also given to them, though Novatian was not their
> founder.” (*Ibid.*, p15)

It is too easy to lump groups that disagreed with Rome under the stigma of that genuinely heretical group, the Marcionites. They certainly rejected the Old Testament God and even began disagreeing with parts of the New Testament but the Cathars were a different group. Here, now, is a quote from an answer to the question, “Who were the Cathars?” published in a newspaper many years ago. Although I kept the clip, I did not put the date on it, but here is the whole answer:

> “Further to earlier answers, the roots of the Catholic Church’s
> Inquisition can be traced to the suppression of the Cathars in the
> 13th century. The success of the Cathar movement, particularly in
> southern France, made the Church fearful of losing power. So it
> embarked on a campaign to ‘bring the heretics to justice’, which
> normally involved confession under torture and burning at the stake.
> Thus arose some of the most feared names in history: Simon de
> Montfort, Bernard Gui and Conrad of Marburg.
>
> One of the most infamous was the papal legate Arnaud-Amaury, Abbot of
> Citeaux, who carried out one of the worst atrocities in Church
> history. On July 22, 1209, de Montfot’s ‘crusaders’ took the strategic
> town of Beziers which housed several important Cathars.
>
> When asked how to discern the Cathars from the Catholics in the town,
> Arnaud-Amaury is supposed to have decreed: ‘Kill them all; God will
> recognise his own.’ As many as 15,000 men, women and children were
> massacred, sending shock waves of fear through the region.
> Arnaud-Amaury wrote to Pope Innocent III that: ‘Neither age, nor sex,
> nor status has been spared’.” (Hillary Thompson, Leeds, in Answers to
> Correspondents in *The Daily Mail* newspaper)

Unless sources can be cited to disprove all the sources I have quoted, caution must be maintained so as not to assume that anyone calling the Cathars ‘heretics’ (who didn’t believe in the God of the Old Testament) were correct. As my answer shows, the Marcionites definitely answered to that charge, but where is the proof that the Cathars shared the same heretical views?

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Puritans are a completely different denomination. In America they were known for their intolerance and violence against people of other denominations and they believed in the Old Testament deity. The Cathars in the Middle Ages was a group who condemned the Old Testament deity and were very peaceful.

Comment: All the things I have read about the Cathars say they were dualists who believed that Jesus worshipped a god of love entirely different and in opposition to the Old Testament god.

Comment: @freethinker36  No doubt you have read such accusations, but who made those claims, and why? Surely you could cite sources? Share with us the evidence for thinking the charges were true. Also, bear in mind that the word 'Puritans' meant different things to different peoples in different centuries. Their history has roots going right back to the start of the 4th century, for Cathars were also called Puritans after the time of Constantine the Great. They did not take that name themselves, but were given it. I shall add an Edit to my answer to say more, in response.

Comment: Either you are mistaken, confusing the term with something else or you are using a very obscure term in contraposition of the regular use of the term Puritan or I am missing something. Just check the entry of Puritan or Puritanism in Britannica.

Comment: @freethinker36 I have simply quoted all of that from a sound source, The Pilgrim Church by E.H. Broadbent, published in 1931 (Pickering Classic reprint 1985). Broadbent cites  Marcion das /evangelium vom Fremden Gott (Ad. v. Harnack) re. the Marcionites, and The Later Roman Empire, Prof. J.B. Bury Vol.1, c.9 re. Novatian and the Donatists. The name of 'Puritans' goes much further back than most people suppose. The originals may have differed in some respects to 15th century Puritans but their roots to back to Constantine's era.

Comment: Much of the information here is wrong, or Broadbent is using "Cathars" in a completely different way from how everybody else is using it. Please have a look at [the standard definition of "Cathars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism). If you want to stand by your statements about Catharism then please find sources to back you up. Even your quotes from Broadbent do not back up your claims.

Comment: @DJCClayworth  These are not 'my' statements about the Cathars, they are Broadbents.  His 400-page, 10-times-reprinted classic on the history of groups outside of Catholicism (over 1,800 years) cites 71 scholarly writings. But he spent nearly 50 years traveling in Central and Eastern Europe to personally gather information about these oft-maligned and misrepresented groups. Needless to say, his report is not liked by those who think that only the Catholic account is sound. But his work is scholarly and has stood intact since 1931. Broadbent died in 1945.

Comment: So can you give us a quote from Broadbent to explain why he calls all these people  (like the Donatists, Novations and Puritans) "Cathars" when everybody else just uses the term "Cathars" to refer to a specific 12th century group who didn't hold to the same scripture we do? Especially why did he call the Puritans "Cathars" when they had extremely different beliefs from 12thC French Cathars?

Comment: @DJCClayworth  Not without spending many hours going through nearly 400 pages! It seems likely that any church history that clashes significantly with the Catholic account of those it persecuted to near extinction while destroying virtually all written records they had or which were written about them by non-Catholics, is going to hit a brick wall. This has happened here. Yes, there were heretics. Yes, their spread had to be opposed. The point is, have some been lumped in with them who should not have been? So often all groups refusing to baptise infants, refusing to bend the knee to

Comment: the pope etc. were labelled heretics. Who today can really sift through the murk of centuries past when most of the evidence has been actively destroyed, as well as the supposed heretics? Words and titles used long before the 12thC complicate the matter if we think they always meant the same people with the same beliefs. Broadbent traces developments over 1,800 years.  If you read his book you will see the problems he was up against, yet how methodical he remained throughout.

Comment: You've written something the clashes hugely with what other historians say, including non-Catholic historians. So you really need to find sources to back it up. In any case, the question was almost certainly about the 12th Century movement called "Cathars", so your answer probably still isn't relevant.

Comment: Yes, my question is about the Cathars of the Languedoc region of 12th century Europe.

Comment: @freethinker36  Ah! Only part of my answer applies to that, then. I've used a minority report, which many will dismiss, but at least the author is known, and his Christian stance is shown in his book, which is more than can be said for most Wikipedia entries. (Note to self: explore why modern, anonymous on-line entries are often accepted unquestioningly, and whether I need to do something about that regarding myself, on Stack!)